# Applying a custom aggregation function to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with two float columns, `col_x` and `col_y`.

I want to return the sum of `col_x * col_y` divided by the sum of `col_x`

Can this be done with a custom aggregate function?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd


def aggregation_function(x, y):
    return sum(x * y) / sum(x)


df = pd.DataFrame([(0.1, 0.2), (0.3, 0.4), (0.5, 0.6)], columns=["col_x", "col_y"])
result = df.agg(aggregation_function, axis="columns", args=("col_x", "col_y"))
```

I know that the aggregation function probably doesn't make sense but I can't even get to the point where I can try other things because I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: apply() got multiple values for keyword argument 'args'
```

I don't know how else I can specify the `args` for my aggregation function. I've tried using `kwargs`, too but nothing I do will work. There is no example in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) for this but it seems to say that it is possible.

How can you specify the args for the aggregation function?

The desired result of the output aggregation would be a single value

Comment: is your expected output a scalar or a series? can you post the desired result too. thanks

Comment: Yes it would be a scalar value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , you can use `apply` on `axis=1` for such problems:

```
df.apply(lambda x: aggregation_function(x['col_x'],x['col_y']),axis=1)
```

however , this will result in error in your case because the aggregate function you have is calculating `col_x * col_y` for each row, sum doesnot work with a scalar value , it needs an iterable:

> Signature: sum(iterable, start=0, /)
> Docstring:
> Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

Hence `sum(0.2)` doesnot work.

If we remove the sum from the aggregate function , this works as intended:

```
def aggregation_function(x, y):return (x * y)/ x
df.apply(lambda x: aggregation_function(x['col_x'],x['col_y']),axis=1)

0    0.2
1    0.4
2    0.6
dtype: float64
```

However as you say you want to divide sum of `col_x` with the result of multiplication of `col_x` and `col_y` , you can tweak the function and use `series.sum` and use it directly with the dataframe though this can be vectorized to `df['col_x'].mul(df['col_y']).sum()/df['col_x'].sum()`

```
def aggregation_function(x, y): return (x * y).sum() / x.sum()
aggregation_function(df['col_x'],df['col_y'])

0.4888888888888889
```